# Ember createRecord not creating relationships

Tags: javascript, django, ember.js, ember-data, django-rest-framework

I'm using the latest ember and ember-data as of this post. My setup includes django, django-rest-framework. My adapter is ember-data-django-rest-adapter.

I have these models

```
App.Game = DS.Model.extend({
    name:           DS.attr('string'),
    thumbnail:      DS.attr('string'),
    images:         DS.hasMany('image', {async: true}),
    spritesheets:   DS.hasMany('spritesheet', {async: true})
});

App.Image = DS.Model.extend({
    name:           DS.attr('string'),
    absolute_url:   DS.attr('string'),
    game:           DS.belongsTo('game', {async: true}),
    spritesheet:    DS.belongsTo('spritesheet', {async: true})
});

App.Spritesheet = DS.Model.extend({
    name:           DS.attr('string'),
    columns:        DS.attr('number'),
    rows:           DS.attr('number'),
    cell_width:     DS.attr('number'),
    cell_height:    DS.attr('number'),
    game:           DS.belongsTo('game', {async: true}),
    image:          DS.belongsTo('image', {async: true}),
    animations:     DS.hasMany('animation', {async: true})
});

App.Animation = DS.Model.extend({
    name:           DS.attr('string'),
    spritesheet:    DS.belongsTo('spritesheet', {async: true}),
});
```

And this Route:

```
App.AnimationsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        var store = this.store;
        var image = this.modelFor('image');
        var game = this.modelFor('game');
        var spritesheet = image.get('spritesheet');
        console.log(game)
        if (spritesheet === null) {
            spritesheet = store.createRecord('spritesheet',{
                name: 'test',
                game: game,
                image: image
            });
            console.log(spritesheet.toJSON())

        }
        return spritesheet.get('animations');
    }
});
```

There is obviously more code but this is the bit that is causing me the problem. The rest of it is working fine. The game model is loading fine as is the image.

My problem is that the 'image' & 'game' attributes are set to 'undefined'.
This is the json output in the console:

```
Object {name: "test", columns: null, rows: null, cell_width: null, cell_height: null…}
{
    cell_height: null,
    cell_width: null,
    columns: null,
    game: undefined,
    image: undefined,
    name: "test",
    rows: null
}
```

I've been going crazy with this for ages. Any clues anyone?
Also, I know I probably shouldn't be doing the create in the route but I'm just trying to get it to work for now

Comment: Isn't it a result of using ``{async: true}``? Value could appear after your AJAX request.

Comment: @niekas Thanks. Removing async worked. Which I don't understand as the game and image records were already loaded. Is there a way I could get this to work without removing the async attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues open with belongsTo async, it currently doesn't allow assignment.

https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1535

https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1542

Comment: Sorry, that was in my code, just a typo. I've updated it now.

Comment: I tried that one with the same results. I've kind of fixed it now by removing async from the attributes on the spritesheet. Although I still don't know how it fixed it but it works. I can't find any documentation on how async actually works though.

Comment: yeah documentation is very non-existent while they are still hardening ED.

Comment: Is the are some fix avalible